# SurfaceView vs TextureView for Camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, textureview

I want to incorporate a camera feature in my app, that will allow layout transitions of the view itself, changing its size, its preview size, and handle orientation changes efficiently. Should I use `TextureView` or `SurfaceView`?

Decisions decisions..

Comment: You can find various examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), where SurfaceView and TextureView are used for camera preview and video playback.  Generally speaking, SurfaceView is more efficient at displaying images, but TextureView is more flexible.  For example, compare how the aspect ratio is set for video playback in PlayMovieActivity vs. PlayMovieSurfaceActivity -- the former uses a transformation matrix, the latter requires a custom frame layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to your context I suggest `TextureView` because things like transformations, animations and scaling is not possible with the `SurfaceView`. But keep in mind `TextureView` will consume more memory than `SurfaceView`.